# Adjust the size of the banner from the desktop version to the mobile version

Tags: jquery, html, css

I uploaded an image of a banner to my website 728 x 90, but when I open my web site vi mobile phone, the banner image is large and not adjusted for the mobile version.

This is the code that I am using for the banner:

```
<a href="https://m.do.co/c/a9fe6126cjhll" target="_blank">
  <img src="img/do.jpg" class="banner" alt="banner">
</a>
```

so how can I adjust the size of that banner image to fit for mobile version ?

Comment: Just set the width of the image 100%

Comment: You can either set `img{ width:100%; }`  --  Or use `media queries` to adjust the size at specific `break points`  https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: In addition to the above, make sure you're also using the correct meta tags.

Comment: He shouldn't do img{width: 100%;} that forces any future images to 100% by default. Instead he should use the class to make it 100% width.

Answer (score 0):

Do a style like this:

```
.banner {
    width: 100%;
}
```

If you want the image to be less than 100 percent wide but centered than you can do something like this:

```
.banner {
    width: 60%;
    margin: auto;
}
```